# Is there any layman proof or explanation for area as an definite integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, area

I am reading a [chapter on integrals](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lemh201.pdf#page=49) from a School textbook. In the chapter, a function called the area function is defined based on the definite integral. It is as follows

$$A(x) = \int\limits_{a}^{x} f(x) dx$$

The following are two theorems are given in the textbook

Theorem 1

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and
> let $A(x)$ be the area function. Then $A'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in
>  [a, b]$

Theorem 2

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and
> $F$ be an anti-derivative function of $f$. Then $\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = [F(x)]_{a}^{b} = F(b)-F(a)$.

but it is mentioned that the proof of the theorems stated is beyond the scope of the book I am studying.

Is there any elementary or layman proof/explanation for understanding **how the definite integral quantifies the area under the curve**?

Comment: in the last sentence do you mean "how the **definite** integral..."? because the indefinite integral has nothing to do with areas. An indefinite integral is more properly referred to as an antiderivative; this is the appropriate terminology since it is literally the opposite of differentiation. Also, I'm sure every presentation on the definite integral motivates it by relating it to the (signed) area bounded by a graph of a (nice enough) function and the horizontal axis.

Comment: The connection between antiderivatives and the area function is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. One way to get an intuitive idea of why it's true is to imagine the area under a curve $y=f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=t$, and then: if $t$ changes a little bit $dx$, then the area changes roughly by the skinny rectangle of area $f(t)dx$, so the RATE of change of area w.r.t $x$ is (approx.)  $f(t)dx/dx=f(t)$. That is, the derivative of the area function at $x=t$ is $f(t)$, i.e. $A'(t)=f(t)$ where $A$ is the area function.

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to learn the underlying theory is to find the right Real Analysis (AKA Calculus) textbook for you.  Perhaps one that combines problem solving with theorems, and forces you to be rigorous.  Calculus 2nd Ed. Volumes I and II (separate books) : [Tom Apostol : 1966] was recommended to me, and turned out to be the right book for me.  That does not imply that it will necessarily be the right book for you.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks...

Comment: "Area under the curve" can be a slippery notion. First, unless the integral has bounds like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty,$ it's only giving you area under *part* of a curve. Second, it only counts area from the curve down to the $x$ axis--otherwise the area would be infinite. Third, we have to get creative about what we mean by "area under the curve" when the curve dips below the $x$ axis.

Comment: There is a good correspondence between definite integration and "area under a curve" under certain conditions. I tried to explain this in my answer to [What do the bounds of a definite integral represent geometrically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1355457/139123) The accepted answer to the same question gives a good illustration of the kind of graphical picture people have in mind when they say a definite integral gives the area under a curve.

Comment: I also note that your textbook also explained the connection between (some) indefinite integrals and the area under (some) curves several pages earlier. The "area function" in the question is just a particular indefinite integral they described at the point they do because that particular integral occurs in the the second fundamental theorem of calculus ("Theorem 2" in the question).

Comment: Does your text mention Riemann sums at all?

Comment: @CameronWilliams No.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written, the first fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then for all $x\in[a,b]$,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt=f(x) \, .
$$
To understand why, note that by the definition of the derivative,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{a}^{x+h}f(t) \, dt-\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t) \, dt}{h} \, .
$$
In a real analysis course, you will be given the tools to prove rigorously that this limit is equal to $f(x)$. However, if you are just looking for intuition, then consider how if $h$ is very small, then $\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t) \, dt$ is the area of an approximately rectangular shape, with width $h$ and $f(x)$:

[image: Visualising the first fundamental theorem of calculus]

As $h\to0$, any difference between $\int_{x}^{x+h}f(x) \, dx$ and the area of a rectangle becomes negligible. Hence,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t) \, dt}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\cdot f(x)}{h}=f(x)
$$
This result is called "fundamental" for two reasons. First, there is no reason, *a priori*, to think that integration (finding the area under the curve) has anything to do with differentiation (finding the tangent to a curve); the first fundamental theorem of calculus shows that they are in fact intimately related. Second, the first fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that if $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then it must be the derivative of some function on that interval, namely $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt$. This is crucial in proving the second fundamental theorem of calculus.

The second fundamental theorem of calculus is now a simple corollary of the first. Suppose that $S$ and $F$ are both antiderivatives of $f$ on $[a,b]$, where $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt$. Then, since $S'(x)=F'(x)$, there must be a number $C$ such that
$$
S(x)=F(x)+C=\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt+C
$$
for all $x\in[a,b]$. To find the value of $C$, set $x=a$. Then,
$$
S(a)=F(a)+C=\int_{a}^{a}f(t) \, dt + C= C
$$
Hence, $S(x)-S(a)=F(x)$. Setting $x=b$, this becomes $S(b)-S(a)=F(b)$, or
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(t) \, dt = S(b)-S(a) \, .
$$
NB the term "second fundamental theorem of calculus" is also sometimes used to describe a stronger result, where we don't even need to assume that $f$ is continuous. Again, this would be covered in a real analysis course.